# Angular routing: Home page URL should be http://localhost:4200/

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have done URL routing in my project. When I redirect to the home page URL becomes http://localhost:4200/home.

I want my home page URL to be http://localhost:4200/ instead of http://localhost:4200/home

My app.routing.ts file:

```js
    const routes: Routes = 
    [
     {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
     },
     {
      path: '',
      component: LayoutComponent,
      children: [
       {
         path: 'home',
         loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
       }
      ]
     }
    ];
```

And below is the home.routing.ts file:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
     {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent
     }
    ];
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same using the following way

**app.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren:
      './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren:'./another/another.module#AnotherModule'
    
  }
  
];
```

And in the Home module router

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
       
      },
      {
        path: 'other',
        component: otherComponent,
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks @JoelJoseph It worked after I moved declaration of LayoutComponent from app.module to home.module.

Comment: As I want to be always loaded LayoutComponent so what if I have any another module ex. `TestComponent` from `test.module` So now URL is `localhost:4200/test` so `LayoutComponent` and `TestComponent` should be load. In that case where should I declare test module routing? In home.routing?  If I declare it in app.routing then it won't work.

Comment: if so , in the `app.rotuter.ts` you can create a route  for path ' ' in which you load the `LayoutComponent` and then lazy loaded modules  should be loaded  as children  to that route just like what  i have done   in  home.router.ts

Comment: Thanks @JoelJoseph, Resolved issue by adding `home.module` and `home.routing`. Thanks a lot.